# How to get VM type/size for the nodes in a Service Fabric Cluster?

Tags: virtual-machine, azure-service-fabric

I have a Service Fabric cluster with 5 nodes that I set initially to the type Standard_D1_v2. I wanted to know if there is a way to **programmatically** get the type or size (SKU information) of the nodes in a Service Fabric Cluster. I basically want to retrieve the information 'Standard_D1_v2' about my nodes by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use the REST api.

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachineScaleSets/{vmScaleSet}/skus?api-version={apiVersion}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualmachinescalesets/list-available-skus-for-vms)

- Or use the [ComputeManagementClient](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-arm-compute/latest/VirtualMachineScaleSets.html). How-to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/csharp-manage).

Comment: I used the second method, but I get this exception: Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' in mscorlib.dll. The details are: The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/_Node_1' under resource group 'cluster' was not found. Does the second method work with nodes in SF cluster or is it only for VMs created through Azure portal?

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the resource 'VirtualMachineScaleSets'? You shouldn't try to access a scaleset instance as a virtualMachine resource.

Comment: Yep. I realized that was the problem. It works fine with VirtualMachineScaleSets. Thanks a lot!